# How to manually add element to a bound Combo Box but not add it to the Collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ComboBox that has an ItemsSource bound to an ObservableCollection. I would like to have a NONE value appended to the front of Collection, on the View only. I do not want to actually add this appended value to the bound Collection, only for the ComboBox items. I have been trying `ComboBoxItems` but that doesn't seem to work, as it won't actually add.

This is my XAML:

```
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Developer.Games}" Height="25" Width="177">
                        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <ComboBox x:Name="cb" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Date"/>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="Select Game" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Hidden" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger SourceName="cb" Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentControl>
```

So, I would want my Collection to look like this on the expanded drop-down:

```
NONE
Game1
Game2
Game3
```

Comment: The whole point of a ViewModel, in this case the collection, is to serve the view and ensure it has all the data to show in the view. Why don't you want to add it to the collection if the collection is to serve the view?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want to actually add this appended value to the bound Collection

The short answer is what you bind to your data source is what you see from the control.

With that in mind, what you should do in your case is simply not bind the data source from the outside, but make a new data source with your extra items internally (meaning inside the custom derived class you should be working on) and bind that instead. You just have to make sure you keep your data source in sync with the outer data source, using the standard observable events.

Answer (score 0):

WPF has a way of changing values between the VM and the view using `IValueConverter`. You can do something like this:

```
public class GameListEmptyOptionValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var v = value as ObservableCollection<Game>;
        v?.Insert(0, new Game() { Name = "NONE" });
        return v;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and, to use it, on your view:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:GameListEmptyOptionValueConverter x:Key="GameListEmptyOptionValueConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource GameListEmptyOptionValueConverter}}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CompositeCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-a-compositecollection).
Here is an example based on the XAML code you provided, that adds a ListBoxItem with the text "NONE" as the first item and displays the rest of the objects in the view model.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GamesCollection" Source="{Binding}"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ListBoxItem>NONE</ListBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GamesCollection}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```